# LibGdx android accessing .txt files and turning them to Strings

Tags: java, android, string, libgdx, fileinputstream

This is a libgdx project using gradle if that matters. I have a class that implements screen where I want to draw a string to the display. on Desktop the following code works.

```
try {
        string = readFile("bin/001.txt",Charset.defaultCharset());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And then I can use that string in a Label for a stage. However on the android version I use "assets/001.txt" and get the error VFY: unable to resove static method 11542: Ljava/nio/file/Paths;.g

I then researched it and found a suggestion here

```
FileInputStream fis;
        fis = openFileInput("test.txt");
        StringBuffer fileContent = new StringBuffer("");

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        while ((n = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) 
        { 
          fileContent.append(new String(buffer, 0, n)); 
        }
```

This did not work either because openFileInput is undefined because "Those are methods defined on the Context class" however

"If you are using LibGDX, you need to forego the concept of Activities and Views, since your entire game will now just be a single Activity. To have a main menu when you game starts up doesn't switch the Activity, but just presents a different set of objects to be rendered to the same Activity."

And now I'm lost

Answer (score 3):

To read a file in LibGdx you need to abstract from the underlying. This is because the same application will work in several systems (Desktop, Android, Web, ...).

So to read a file you need to use:

```
FileHandle file = Gdx.files.internal("myfile.txt");
String text = file.readString();
```

The path and location of the files can be summarized in the [documentation](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/File-handling#file-storage-types)